# are modules used in client side javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am learning javascript. I read about how to import and export things between javascript modules. I am making a javascript game which consists of several files. Each defines a class and its methods.

I have two questions:

1. Only one of the files actually contains code that interacts with the DOM, so in the HTML do i need to include `<script src="..."></script>` for every js file? or only the one that deals with the DOM?
2. I first tried only referencing the one js file in the `index.html` and exporting the classes defined in the other js files and importing them in the js files where those classes are used. But no browser seemed to understand the import/export statements? Isn't that done on client side javascript?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need referencing all js file in the index.html, because your game will use other file as the module for entry file. And the module file need to be referenced before the entry file.
2. Yes, export/import can not be used on client side directly, its used in nodejs platform mostly with supporting by some tools like typescript or babel. But you can use them with some tools as told before.

so, i think you can use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transform your code to es5 target firstly, then that you can reference them in browser.

Comment: Babel can transform ES6 import/export to CommonJS equivalent (the modularization system implemented by Node.js) but you need something like webpack, browserify, or rollup in order to bundle the modular scripts, or use [babel-transform-es2015-modules-amd](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-amd/) so that your modules can be loaded client-side using RequireJS.

Comment: This is not true since we can use import / export client side : https://caniuse.com/#search=javascript%20modules. This is not fully supported but everything tends to show we could use it in browsers

Answer (score 0):

If you mean ES6 imports, the `import Whatever from “some-resource”;` statement requires the “some-statement” to be a URL.

Additionally, the “entry point” script should be `<script type=“module” src=“some-url”></script>`. The “module” is what tells the user agent that it is loading a JavaScript module and that `import` statements should be resolved.

You only need to include one `<script>` tag if that one script correctly `imports` the rest of your dependency chain.

Browser support for this is still somewhat limited which is why using webpack or some other build step is still recommended until the feature is fully fleshed out.

Answer (score 0):

currently `import` / `export` syntax is **supported** by [approximatively 97+% of all browser (caniuse.com)](https://caniuse.com/#search=javascript%20modules).

The very first thing is to **put `type="module"` as an attribute of a `<script tag>`** (Eg. `<script type="module">`)

Then you can `import`/`export` in your modules. And **YES** modules need to export a value (variable, function...) to be able to use it in another script, but this is optionnal since you can just execute script without the need to export something.

Documentation:

- [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)
- [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)
- [Very good article on how to use module in browsers](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/)

Keep in mind that is not yet a supported feature and you will need a polyfill if you mind about browser compatibility